# How to convert postmand process into c# program

Tags: postman, httpclient

I have tested the postman successfuly.
[image]
I wonder why my C# always get error.

Here is my program

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
            AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
        formData.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        formData.Add(new StringContent("db_backup_archive_file"), "key");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, formData);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to upload file. Status code: 
                   {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
My program alway get BadRequest

Failed to upload file. Status code: BadRequest